# Are AssertionErrors forbidden if I want to use JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert

I have a method that during a specific point of processing it expects that certain invariants are kept.
To keep this trivial let's say that at point X during the code processing the variable `high` and the variable `low` MUST be divisible.
So in the code I do:

```
if(high % low != 0){  
  throw new AssertionError("Invalid state of low and high [low = "+ low+ ", high=" + high+"]");   
}
```

During unit testing with `JUnits` I had a test case to test for this.
So I did:

```
try {
//At this point I know for sure that the low and high are not divible so process() should throw an Assertion Error
   process();  
   fail();  
} 
catch(AssertionError e){        
}
```

But the test case was green!
But I realised that junit raises an assert error due to `fail` but I catch it and as a result the test case is pass instead of failed.
From my point of view the proper error to raise in my code is also `AssertionError` and not some generic e.g. `IllegalArgumentsException`
So is there a way to fix this so that the test case works or should I not be using the `AssertionError` in my code in the first place? If this is the case, what exception should I be raising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean shouldFail = false;
try {
    callTheMethod();
    shouldFail = true;
}
catch (AssertionError e) {
    // expected
}
if (shouldFail) {
    fail();
}
```

But if the condition is an invariant, then it should always be true, and the AssertionError should thus never be thrown, and you should thus not even be able to unit test it. If you're able to test it, it means that the invariant is not really an invariant, and that the condition might be true depending on the sequence of calls or on the arguments provided. You should thus prefer an IllegalStateExcetion over the AssertionError.

Comment: +1. I don't follow the argument on invariant. You are right it indeed depends on arguments provided (but indirectly, i.e. `high` and `low` are derived from arguments passed) and the fact that `high` and `low` should always be divisible MUST always hold true. Doesn't this constitute them as invariant?

Comment: An invariant is some boolean condition that is guaranteed, by the class itself, to be always true. If this condition is true only if the provided arguments are correct, then it's not an invariant anymore. The way to make it an invariant is to reject the arguments if they would make the invariant false. And to reject illegal arguments, you throw an IllegalArgumentException. For example, a Person class could have as ivariant: `age > 0`. The method setAge(int age) should guarantee this invariant by throwing an IllegalArgumentException if the age is <= 0.

Comment: That's a good solution. Here are two alternatives: (#1) Throw a different exception instead of AssertionError. Make your own exception class, if needed. (#2) I most commonly check the exception message int he catch block: assertEquals("Invalid state of low and high [low = 2, high=11]", e.getMessage())

Comment: I'd better rewrite it as
`try {
    callTheMethod();
   fail("Should never get here")
}
catch (AssertionError e) {
    // expected
}
`

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin that's what the OP had. Read the question again.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have a `try-catch` block in a unit test.  If you expect an exception use an annotation:

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
public void youTestMethod() {
   ...
}
```

You will have to use a different exception such as `IllegalArgumentsException` because JUnit uses `AssertionError` internally.  I find `IllegalArgumentsException` more descriptive of what actually went wrong.

Comment: In my version of JUnit (4.10), it throws java.lang.AssertionError.

Comment: Hmmm you are right, I wonder why they did that.  Do you disagree with using an Annotation here?

Comment: No. But I disagree with using AssertionError. See my answer and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 > should I not be using the AssertionError in my code in the first place?
```

**No** JUnit is using AssertionError and its decendants to tell the junit-runner that a test has failed. (Simmilar applies to .net NUnit-runner)

```
 > If this is the case, what exception should I be raising?
```

I would use one of the generic Exceptoin like `IllegalArgumentsException` or create my own Exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a conflict between your code and JUnit, but it's easy to get around.

When you write a JUnit test case, as you've already deduced, an AssertionError is thrown when the test case has failed.

To let JUnit know that your test case has passed, the test code should NOT throw an AssertionError on any other Exception/Error for that matter.

There will be two test cases (at least) -

A. high and low are exactly divisible - the test case code doesn't throw an AssertionError.

```
//test case setup
yourClass.callYourMethod(4,2);
//verification
```

Here, if the test case behaves correctly, there is no AssertionError and JUnit knows it has passed.

B. high and low are not exactly divisible - the code should throw AssertionError but the test case should not.

```
boolean failed;
try {
    //test case setup
    yourClass.callYourMethod(4,2);
    failed = true;
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    failed = false;
}
if (failed) {
    fail();
}
```